# Is there a function that looks like in the graph attached?

Tags: functions, curves

Is there a function that looks like this? The idea is to find a family of functions where infinitely many of them converge to a point (pictured in orange) and the curves eventually have more distance as between one another as you travel away from the point. However, none of the curves intersect.

[image]

If the curves are differentiable in the orange region, it would be great, but if not, piecewise functions will also work. Ideally, a **single** $f(x,y)$ such that each curve is $f(x,y) = c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is the most desirable.

Comment: Where did the picture come from?

Comment: @YuriyS I drew it.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

There could be many examples consisting of the level curves of some function $f(x,y)=c$.

For example, for $f(x,y)=\left\vert\dfrac{1}{(x-1)(y-2)}\right\vert$ the level curves aproach the point $(1,2)$ in the manner you describe for $c_{2k-1}=2^k$, $c_{2k}=2^{-k}$ when $k$ is a positive integer. In fact, they approach the graph of $(x-1)(y-2)=0$.
[image: graph of level curves]

Comment: I'm sorry this isn't exactly what I'm looking for. The curves do approach a point but the second condition that the curves distance from one another further away from the point does not hold.

Comment: Well, actually, they do. The ones that move further away have $c=\dfrac{1}{2^k}$, so with $c=\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{4},\dfrac{1}{8},\dfrac{1}{16},\dfrac{1}{32},\cdots$ the curves are getting further away and further apart.

Comment: Could you clarify how is that the case? Each curve is asymptotic to the $x$ or $y$ axis. So they converge to the particular axis rather than distancing away from one another, isn't it so?

Comment: So by "distancing themselves from each other" do you mean having different asymptotic behavior, such as different horizontal asymptotes? For any line other than the asymptotes, its intercepts with this set of curves get further apart the further out you go from the point $(1,2)$.